# How do you mock a JobBuilderFactory?

Tags: mockito, spring-batch

I have a spring batch project. I would like to mock up the JobBuilderFactory for junit test. When I do a when().thenReturn I get that the JobBuilderFactory is null.

Comment: Why do you need to mock the JobBuilderFactory? What is the purpose of your test? Please share your code.

Comment: Well I’m trying to write a unit test for a job. When I try to do this without mocks I get that the jobFactoryBuilder is null.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a complete example of how to test a Spring Batch job in the [End-To-End Testing of Batch Jobs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/testing.html#endToEndTesting) section of the reference documentation. As you will see, there is no need to mock the `JobBuilderFactory`.